# android json database list

Tags: android, json, database

Hi I'm new in the world of android. So I tested a tutorial do fetch data from a XAMPP database and list it in my app with listview.
Everything is like in the tutorial, so why my app doesnt't work?
When I start the app i got an error message and the app crushes.

Thank you for your help!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView responseTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    this.responseTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.responseTextView);


    new GetAllCustomerTask().execute(new ApiConnector());


}

public void setTextToTextView(JSONArray jsonArray)
{
    String s  = "";
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s +
                    "ID : "+json.getInt("id")+"\n"+
                    "Name : "+json.getString("name")+"\n\n";
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    this.responseTextView.setText(s);

}


private class GetAllCustomerTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {

        // it is executed on Background thread

        return params[0].GetAllCustomers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        setTextToTextView(jsonArray);


    }
}
```

}

```
public class ApiConnector {

public JSONArray GetAllCustomers()
{
    // URL for getting all customers


    String url = "http://localhost/getAllCustomers.php";

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

    try
    {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();

        //Log Errors Here



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonArray;


}
```

}

This is my logcat

```
04-06 22:17:21.550  23914-23914/diplomarbeit.at.dbfetchcontenttester E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: diplomarbeit.at.dbfetchcontenttester, PID: 23914
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at diplomarbeit.at.dbfetchcontenttester.MainActivity.setTextToTextView(MainActivity.java:34)
        at diplomarbeit.at.dbfetchcontenttester.MainActivity$GetAllCustomerTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:66)
        at diplomarbeit.at.dbfetchcontenttester.MainActivity$GetAllCustomerTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:53)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your MainActivity class code

Comment: the first Code in my post is the main activity!

Comment: Make sure this link is working from phone your http://localhost/getAllCustomers.php

Comment: it works! i posted a link!

Comment: I mean from your phone browser not your computer browser

Comment: it didn't worked from my phone and when i try it with an emulator its the same. I have read the "Null Pointer Exception-Link", i understand the meaning of the error but i don't know how i can fix it in my program. Can u please help me?

Comment: i solved the problem.. i changed the URL from "http://localhost/..." to "http://10.0.2.2/..."

Answer (score 1):

Your jsonArray object when executing `setTextToTextView(JSONArray jsonArray)` seems to be null. I recommend you to use the debugger from Eclipse / Android studio to see where it fails to get data in your `public JSONArray GetAllCustomers()` method. You need first to make sure that you get the data from your local server. If that's the case, maybe take a look at the json parsing.

I'm also assuming you are running this on an emulator and not on a mobile phone/tablet. You are using a localhost address which will only work if your local server is on the same machine as your "device".

Comment: I tested it with an emulator but the result is the same.
When i debug the code the logcat tells me: 

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference

but i can't solve the problem.

why it has worked in the video of the tutorial - it was exactly the same code?!

Answer (score 0):

Your jsonArray has "id":"0" inside of it, because the number is in quotes ("0") I think its being seen as text/String as opposed to an integer:

Currently:

```
"ID : "+json.getInt("id")+"\n"+
```

Try:

```
"ID : "+json.getString("id")+"\n"+
```

If this doesn't make a difference try putting the URL into a web browser on the device you are testing it on to make sure its working on your test device/emulator.

Comment: I tried it, doesn't make a difference.